# Which of these if the correct way to use seekg?

Tags: c++

For an ifstream object A, which statement will position the file-position pointer to the end of a 10 byte file associated with object A?

```
A. A.seekg(0);  
B. A.seekg(0, ios::end);    
C. A.seekg(10, ios::end);   
D. A.seekg(0, ios::beg);
```

Not sure if it's B or C...

Comment: the answer is in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`seekg(a, b)` will set the read position to `b` ***offset*** by `a` bytes.

Thus:

- `A.seekg(0, ios::beg)` is equivalent to `A.seekg(0)`.
- `A.seekg(0, ios::end)` is equivalent to `A.seekg(10)` **if** the file is 10 bytes.
- `A.seekg(10, ios::end)` is equivalent to `A.seekg(20)`. That won't work with a 10-byte file.

The [documentation on `seekg`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/) would have answered your question.

Comment: Interestingly, the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/seekg) explicitly states that *“seekg(n) is not necessarily equivalent to seekg(n, ios::beg).”*.

Comment: @spectras One difference is that `ios::pos_type` and `ios::off_type` are distinct types that could overflow depending on the `seekg` overload.

Answer (score 0):

Googling for "c++ seekg" (quicker than typing the question on SO, incidentally) yields http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/seekg/ among many.

From there we see (greatly abridged):

```
istream& seekg (streamoff off, ios_base::seekdir way);

...

off: Offset value, relative to the way parameter.

way: ... any of the following constant values: 

  ios_base::beg   beginning of the stream
  ios_base::cur   current position in the stream
  ios_base::end   end of the stream
```

From this, using our deductive and critical thinking skills (important general skills to have in programming and useful outside of programming, in general), we can see that to seek to **0** bytes from the **end** of the stream leads to <exercise to reader>.

Hint: 10 bytes from the end is not the end.